# How to split a univariate dataframe into multiple dataframes using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
Y6=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
Y6=pd.DataFrame(data=Y6)
for i in Y6:
   df[i]=Y6.iloc[i:i+1]
print(df[2])
```

Desired Output -

```
    df[1]=[1,2]
    df[2]=[3,4]
```

I would like to split this into 10 dataframes with 2 components in each dataframe.

Comment: You can store these 10 dataframes in a list or a dictionary.

Comment: @J.Kaitlyn Correct, but I first need to pull them out of the dataframe. I don't want to do it manually as I will be working with larger dataframes next.

Comment: The output that I obtain after running this operation contains 0s. Perhaps, I am not implementing the code properly?

Comment: Sorry for the typo. In that case, you just need to make a small change based on Kyle 's answer. dfs = list() for x in range(0, len(Y6), 2): dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([Y6[x:x+2]]))

Comment: @J.Kaitlyn I am seeing more zeros now :(

Comment: Are they the index and column names of dataframes?

Comment: No, it looks like one big data frame with zeros in it.

Comment: Maybe I know what's the problem. I didn't convert list Y6 to dataframe. The completed code should be ` Y6=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]  dfs = list() for x in range(0, len(Y6), 2): dfs.append(pd.DataFrame([Y6[x:x+2]]))`

Comment: @J.Kaitlyn Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want a dataframe of every two values?

I'm still confused at what you are looking for:

```
dfs = list()
for x in range(0, len(Y6), 2):
   df = Y6.iloc[x:x+2].T
   df.columns= ['one', 'two']
   dfs.append(df)

for df in dfs:
   print(df)
   print()
```

Result is 10 dataframes, each with one row, each with 2 items from the original df:

```
   one  two
0    1    2

   one  two
0    3    4

   one  two
0    5    6

   one  two
0    7    8

   one  two
0    9   10

   one  two
0   11   12

   one  two
0   13   14

   one  two
0   15   16

   one  two
0   17   18

   one  two
0   19   20
```

Comment: I need dataframes, not lists.

Comment: That should give you a list of dataframes. Please update the question to show the desired output.

Comment: Point noted. I have made the changes.